# Creating RSS feed with simpleXMLElement

Tags: php

I have to create a rss feed as I understand but I absolutely don't understand how this have to be done.
What I did so far is:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLExtended("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
        $channel = $xml->addChild("channel");
        $channel->addChild("title", "Kidso");
        $channel->addChild("link", "https://kidso.bg");
        $channel->addChild("description", "Kidso");
```

And have some data for each `<item>` but to simplify my question this the begining. My `<item>` has a prefix to all of its fields. For example this one:

```
<item>
<g:id>26929</g:id>
<g:title>
<![CDATA[ Подложка за спане с матрак InterBaby, сива ]]>
</g:title>
</item>
```

When I try to create a xml file I get this error:

```
error on line 2 at column 124: Namespace prefix g on title is not defined
```

And than I saw that in my example feed I have `<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">` this line instead of normal xml opening tag. How should I create such rss feed with my data ?

**EDIT**: The extened class

```
<?php

class SimpleXMLExtended extends SimpleXMLElement {
    public function addCData($cdata_text) {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($this);
        $no   = $node->ownerDocument;
        $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($cdata_text));
    }
}
```

It is only for adding CDATA.

Comment: Your code is nothing close to what XML example you provide. Maybe you have some other XML generator?

Comment: I have added the extended class. But the method there is only used to create CDATA field.